# How can I obtain statistics (requests per second, response time) for an app hosted on Cloud Foundry Pivotal?

Tags: monitoring, cloud-foundry

I am trying to obtain statistics for an app which is hosted on my Cloud Foundry Pivotal without using any 3rd party applications like "AppDynamics" (or others).

Specifically, I want to find out the **'Requests per second' and 'Response Time'.**

I know that it is possible to access memory, disk space and cpu utilization by an app because Pivotal provides these statistics. So does Pivotal also provide 'Requests per second' and 'Response Time'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is pretty easy to use.  You can use Logstash as the ingesting engine, you just need the correct parser.  Check out http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2014/02/20/cloud-foundry-and-logstash for the parser and config for ingesting cloud foundry logs.  I was playing around with this before and it worked quite well.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: This looks great :) Thanks for the advice, will write back if I'm stuck anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to logging the requests to an external logging provider.  Check out http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management-thirdparty-svc.html.  You can actually log to any http endpoint that supports POST.  You can use Splunk to calculate your response time and requests per second.  The logs that come out of that are in real time and are streamed to your logging endpoint.  It contains information about the requests as well as log messages from your app.

ex.

```
2014-11-10T11:12:47.97-0500 [App/0]   OUT GET / 304 5ms
2014-11-10T11:12:48.36-0500 [App/0]   OUT GET /favicon.ico 404 0ms
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response but as I stated I'm looking for a way to do this without using any third party services which charge money. Splunk has a free account for around 300 mb of logs a month and I need much more than that :(

Comment: I'm thinking of using ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash and Kibana) to get the logs and go from there since its open source.

Answer (score 0):

There are basic stats available when you run `cf app <app-name>`.  These include the memory, cpu and disk utilization of your app.  You can also access these via the REST api, documented here.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cc-api-docs/41397913/apps/get_detailed_stats_for_a_started_app.html

That's not going to help with requests per second or response time though.  @jsloyer's solution would work for that, or you could use an APM like NewRelic, which will give you a wealth of data for virtually nothing.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I can get memory, disk space and cpu utilization from a curl request. But trying to get the reqs/sec and response time from a 3rd party software for massive logs is never free, so I'm trying out ELK. http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2014/08/14/elk-one-vagrant-box/

Comment: I've personally found that the stats provided with a free NewRelic account are quite good.  No idea if they'll cover your needs.  I only mention it because NR tends to work very well with apps pushed to CF.  Running your own solution is great too, it just means you have to set everything up and run it somewhere.